# How to debug requireJS module defined path/file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I'm new to RequireJS world. I'm getting `Load Timeout error` for one of the modules, which I've already defined in the main file. I don't see any request in Network tab of Chrome, probably because require has already loaded that file earlier.

I've hooked to `onError` event of require & I see the error. But the stack doesn't give the exact location/name of the file which tried to load this module. Is there any way to figure out the exact file/linesOfCode ?

Also, is there any way to figure out at runtime all paths that are defined in requireJS, some API like `require.getPaths()`

Comment: It is absolutely infuriating that a typo in a path name is so impossible to track down. Thanks, require

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
requirejs.s.contexts._.config.paths
```

This will return all paths defined in requirejs. If there are multiple `.config` calls, it seems to contain all with no duplicates.