# Is there a way to print out the dependencies requirejs thinks it is using at runtime?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-routing, fancytree

I have an application using Backbone.js and requirejs. I'm seeing some incredibly weird behavior where a library, after being properly loaded from the path provided in the requirejs config, fails on load to a totally random path as a dependency of a file that doesn't even list it as a requirement (using CommonJS syntax), or as far as I can tell have that dependency in any of it's dependencies.

In order to debug this problem, I'd like to print at runtime, or step through using the debugger at runtime, what's causing what to load in requirejs. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug requireJS module defined path/file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462403/how-to-debug-requirejs-module-defined-path-file)

Comment: After extensive searching, I found my answer at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462403/how-to-debug-requirejs-module-defined-path-file, and believe my question is a duplicate. Instead of using requirejs.s.contexts._.config.paths, though, I used requirejs.s.contexts._.config.defined to see what each path was defined as. A lot of relative paths are being defined as either fancytree or backbone.js instead of the actual file, even though the path is correct.